# Copying Charts from Excel fails

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, office-addins, excel-addins

I want to copy a chart from Excel.

```cs
var chart = (ChartObject)allCharts.Item("SomeChart");
chart.Select();
chart.Copy();
```

The problem is, for some chart types copying failes with `Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))`:

- Treemap
- Waterfall
- Sunburst
- Funnel
- Histogram
- Pareto
- Box and Whisker

As I am not sure, whether this is a full list, I want to somehow check the chart object before copying it.

So far, I found out two clues:

- There is a [`_Chart.Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._chart.type.aspx), which is "Reserved for internal use." as Microsoft states. The Type gets a value of `-1` for the objects above and some other values otherwise.
- [`_Chart.ChartType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlcharttype.aspx) Enum seems not to include the objects above and returns an `int` value and no names like `XlChartType.xlPieExploded`.

The question is, can I rely on any of these two peculiarities or is there another way to prevent copy failure?